# Should I exclude security from controller unit tests?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

In my Spring application, I want to write tests. So, the "/companies" endpoint is secured and requires an ADMIN or USER role. In unit tests, should I bypass security and focus only on the business logic, and then test with security in integration tests? Or should I rather consider security in unit tests?

Without security:

```
@WebMvcTest(CompanyController.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)
class CompanyControllerTest2 {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private CompanyService companyService;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @MockBean
    private ResourceAccessHelper resourceAccessHelper;

    @MockBean
    private TokenAuthenticationFilter tokenAuthenticationFilter;

    @Test
    void shouldCreateCompany() throws Exception {
        CompanyDto companyDto = CompanyDto.builder().companyName("My   Company").description("Description").build();
        CompanyDto savedCompany = companyDto;
        savedCompany.setId(1L);

        given(companyService.saveNewCompany(companyDto)).willReturn(savedCompany);

        mockMvc.perform(post("/companies")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(companyDto)))
                .andExpect(status().isCreated())
                .andExpect(header().exists("Location"));
    }
}
```

Or use here @WithMockUser(username = "user", roles = SecurityConfig.USER) for example?
Which option is a better choice?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What I would do (and have done) is bypass security on unit/component tests(that need to test a class or specific layer) and add security in integration tests.

Comment: And how did you bypass security? By using AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false) annotation, or using different profile or in some other way?

Comment: In my case, it was with AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false).